# Why is the normal force equal to zero at the top of a rollercoaster if the speed is the minimum?

Tags: kinematics

I was practicing for one of my physics exams and there was a problem that asked for the minimum speed a rollercoaster would have to go for its riders to not fall out at the top of a loop. I did the problem but I'm having trouble understanding why the normal force here would be equal to zero. If they're supposed to stay in their seats, shouldn't there be a normal force on the riders by the seat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At minimum speed, at the top, the centrifugal force of the loop is equal to the centripetal force (gravity). So the upside down riders are neither pushed into the seat by centrifugal force, nor are they pulled down against the restraints by gravity, as at the correct speed these two forces equal, and cancel each other out, to essentially create a freefall effect. So there is 0 normal force between the seat and riders as they are in freefall with the seat.

Answer (score 0):

This is why its called the minimum velocity the rollercoaster should have , less than that its a crush.
So the equation is: mg + n= mv^2/R
Let's arrange that ...
N=m(V^2/R-g)
N is defined to be the normal which is a force excreted perpendicular to the touching point of two surfaces. Therefore if N equal to zero there is no touching point between the bodies , implying the man on the rollercoaster is gonna have a rough ride

Answer (score 0):

In the case of minimum speed, then no. In this case, at the top of the loop, the centripetal acceleration is exactly equal to g.

Answer (score 0):

No, because both things (rider and seat) are in free fall towards the earth, so there is no reason why they should turn against each other. (The gravitational attraction force between them is to be neglected in comparison with the gravitational pull exerted on both by the earth.) Normal force is an electromagnetic repulsion force that arises when two things are pressed against each other, but there must exist a prior reason for that contact, which is missing here, since as I said the two things are free-falling.